# undefined symbol: gdk_display_get_primary_monitor

Tags: gtk, undefined, symbols, gdk

I was trying to launch TuringBot software that I just installed on my Linux 16.04, and I got an error:

```
./TuringBot: symbol lookup error: ./TuringBot: undefined symbol: gdk_display_get_primary_monitor
```

I have tried upgrading my system

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but the problem still exists. Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you mean Ubuntu 16.04 (as "Linux 16.04" doesn't exist).

The reason why it doesn't work is because the GTK version of Ubuntu 16.04 is too old ([it has version 3.18.9](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0)) while `gdk_display_get_primary_monitor()` was only added in GTK 3.22.

The easiest way to fix it is probably to upgrade to a newer Ubuntu version.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes you are correct, what I meant was Ubuntu 16.04